# AMD Radeon HD 7470M proprietary driver not working on ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I have manually tried to install AMD Radeon HD 7470M proprietary drivers from AMD official site. But after installing when I tried to launch Catalyst Control Center, a message is shown like this:

> There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.
>
> It could be caused by the following:
>
> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
> Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.

I am using Ubuntu 64-bit 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 2):

[Your card is not supported](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) by any driver, closed or open source.

You need to use what is working for you at the moment and wait for AMD to start supporting your card via their drivers.

Comment: here is the link to check for AMD driver availability http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx